# How to delete data in table through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created a basic form which inputs the values and stores them in an array; I created an `add` function, now I want to a create a `delete` function.

But I don't understand: how can I delete a selected element from my table? Also, I want to edit the values in the table. How can I update vales in my table?

```
<div align="center">
    <h1>User Form</h1>
    <hr>
    <label>User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sname" /><br><br>

     <label>User Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sage" /><br><br>

    <label>User Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="semail" /><br><br>

         <button onclick="add()">Add</button>


</div>
<br><br>
<table align="center" width="1000px" border="2px" id="table">


  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>

    <th>Age</th>

    <th>Email</th>

    <th>Delete</th>

    <th>Update</th>

  </tr>
  <tr id="myRow1">

    <td id="uname">&nbsp;</td>

    <td id="uage">&nbsp;</td>

    <td id="uemail">&nbsp;</td>



  </tr>


</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

var cityArray = [];

//add function    
function add() {



var inputName = document.getElementById("sname");

var inputAge = document.getElementById("sage");

var inputEmail = document.getElementById("semail");

var user={
    Name:inputName.value,
    Email:inputEmail.value,
    Age:inputAge.value

}
console.log(inputName);  
  for(var key in user) 
  {
    cityArray.push(user[key]);

}
 console.log(cityArray);



var table=document.getElementById('table');

var row=table.insertRow();
var cell0=row.insertCell(0);
var cell1=row.insertCell(1);
var cell2=row.insertCell(2);
var cell3=row.insertCell(3);
var cell4=row.insertCell(4);


cell0.innerHTML=user.Name;

cell1.innerHTML=user.Age;

cell2.innerHTML=user.Email;

cell3.innerHTML="<input type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow()'>";
cell4.innerHTML="<input type='submit' value='Update' onclick='edit()'>";

}
function del(){
.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete whole table do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("table").remove();
```

If you want to remove specified row just give him id and replace table with id of row in fuction above.
To update some element instead of .remove() use

```
document.getElementById("ROW_ID").innerHTML="something";
```

And what do you mean by "selected element"?

Comment: No i want to delete only the selected row. how should i set its id?

Comment: But how you select row?With what? If you want, for example, to remove  uname you will write document.getElementById("uname").remove.

Comment: function deleteRow() {
  var row=document.getElementById('table');

  // var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
    table.deleteCell(myRow1);
}

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Fahad, I think the faster solution is to use a little bit of JQuery. First you need to assign an id while your adding cell properties:

```
 cell4.innerHTML="<input id="test" type='submit' value='Update' 
onclick='edit()'>";
```

I put "test" as an id but you can use whatever you want. Then you enter the JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on("click",function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Let me know!